# Erro ao consultar arquivos em um vetor

Tags: java, array, classes, objetos, método

Salve rapaziada, estou com um problema ao fazer esse exercício, meu código é de um sistema simples de locadora, onde eu cadastro filmes, com o código, título e gênero do filme, ao inserir os arquivos em um vetor o código diz que a operação foi realizada com sucesso, mas ao consultar ele não encontra no vetor. Alguém pode me ajudar?

meu código principal:

```
package AtividadeClasses;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char opcao;
//instancia o vetor
        FilmeVet locadora = new FilmeVet(30);
        do {
            System.out.println("1.Cadastrar um filme no arquivo(vetor)\n" + "2.Consultar filmes por gênero\n"
                    + "3.Excluir um filme do arquivo pelo nome\n" + "4.Finalizar operações\n");
            opcao = scan.next().charAt(0);
            switch (opcao) {
            case '1':
                cadastrarFilmes(locadora);
                break;
            case '2':
                pesquisarFilme(locadora);
                break;
            case '3':
                excluirFilme(locadora);
                break;
            case '4':
                System.out.println("Fim do programa");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("opção inválida. Tente novamente.");
            }
        } while (opcao != '5');

    }

    static void cadastrarFilmes(FilmeVet t) {
        Filme filme = new Filme();
        int codigo, genero;
        String nome;
        System.out.println("Digite o código do filme:");
        codigo = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o título do filme:");
        nome = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Digite o genero do filme:"
                + "\n[1]Ação"
                + "\n[2]Drama"
                + "\n[3]Terror");
        genero = scan.nextInt();
        filme = new Filme(codigo, nome, genero);
        if (t.inserirDados(filme)) {
            System.out.println("operação realizada com sucesso.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("operação não realizada. Arquivo cheio.");
        }
    }

    static void pesquisarFilme(FilmeVet t) {
        int posicao, genero;
        System.out.println("Digite o genero do filme:"
                + "\n[1]Ação"
                + "\n[2]Drama"
                + "\n[3]Terror");
        genero = scan.nextInt();
        posicao = t.pesquisarGenero(genero);
        if (posicao == t.getQuantVetor()) {
            System.out.println("o filme não foi encontrado.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(t.getVetor(posicao));
        }
    }

    static void excluirFilme(FilmeVet t) {
        String nome;
        System.out.println("Digite o nome do filme:");
        nome = scan.next();
        if (t.removerDados(nome)) {
            System.out.println("operação realizada com sucesso.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("operação não realizada. Aluno não encontrada.");
        }
    }
}
```

minha classe Filme:

```
package AtividadeClasses;

public class Filme {
    // declaração de atributos
    private int codigo;
    private String nomeFilme;
    private int genero;
    
    public Filme(int codigo, String nomeFilme, int genero) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nomeFilme = nomeFilme;
        this.genero = genero;
    }
    
    public Filme() {
        this.codigo = 0;
        this.nomeFilme = "";
        this.genero = 0;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNomeFilme() {
        return nomeFilme;
    }

    public void setNomeFilme(String nomeFilme) {
        this.nomeFilme = nomeFilme;
    }

    public int getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(int genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    
    public String toString() {
        return "\nCodigo: " + codigo + "\n Título: " + nomeFilme + "\n Gênero: " + genero + "";
    }
}
```

e minha classe para armazenar o filme no vetor:

```
package AtividadeClasses;

public class FilmeVet {
    // declaração de atributos
    private Filme[] vetor;
    private int quantVetor;

    // construtor
    public FilmeVet(int tamanho) {
        this.vetor = new Filme[tamanho];
        this.quantVetor = 0;
    }

    // getters e setters
    public Filme getVetor(int indice) { // retorna somente um aluno
        return this.vetor[indice];
    }

    public void setVetor(int indice, Filme novo) { // altera somente um aluno
        this.vetor[indice] = novo;
    }

    public int getQuantVetor() {
        return quantVetor;
    }

    public void setQuantVetor(int novo) {
        this.quantVetor = novo;
    }

    // mostrar todos os dados do objeto vetor
    public String toString() {
        String resposta = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.quantVetor; i++) {
            resposta += (i + 1) + "." + this.vetor[i].toString();
        }
        return resposta;
    }

    // inserir um filme no objeto vetor
    public boolean inserirDados(Filme novo) {
        if (this.quantVetor == this.vetor.length) {// saber se o arquivo cheio
            return false;
        } else {
            this.vetor[this.quantVetor] = novo;
            this.quantVetor++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // consultar filme por gênero
    public int pesquisarGenero(int genero) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.quantVetor; i++) {
            if (this.vetor[i].getCodigo() == genero) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return this.quantVetor;
    }

    // remover um filme do objeto vetor
    public boolean removerDados(String nome) {
        if (this.quantVetor == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < this.quantVetor && this.vetor[i].getNomeFilme() != nome) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i == this.quantVetor) {
                return false;
            } else {
                this.vetor[i] = this.vetor[this.quantVetor - 1];
                this.quantVetor--;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ficarei grato se alguém puder me ajudar

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

vamos lá: O problema no código está na função inserirDados da classe FilmeVet. Atualmente, a função adiciona um novo filme ao vetor, mas não atualiza o contador quantVetor, o que faz com que o vetor pareça estar vazio durante a pesquisa. Para corrigir isso, basta atualizar o contador após inserir um novo filme.

Altere a função inserirDados da classe FilmeVet para:

```
public boolean inserirDados(Filme filme) {
    if (quantVetor < vetor.length) {
        vetor[quantVetor++] = filme;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note que agora atualizei o contador quantVetor++ após inserir o novo filme no vetor. Isso garante que o contador reflita a quantidade atual de filmes armazenados no vetor.